# Calculating number of days between a date and today in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, count, days

I want to calculate number of days from a date.

For example, we have `@date='03/16/2012'`. I want to get number of days up to now.

How can I do it?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I had calculated it at front end and i wanted to calculate it from database

Comment: You need to define your method of counting. Counting discrete calendar dates is not the same as continuous blocks of 24 hours.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
datediff(day, @date, getdate())
```

[datediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)